# MongoDB Altas Compound $search: how to combine one AND condition and two OR in the same search query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

I have a collection with Atlas search index, created for full-text search by two fields. Also, I need to search only through records with a specific value of a third field:

```
Collection {
  name: String         # search by -> $search.autocomplete
  description: String  # search by -> $search.autocomplete
  isAvailable: Boolean # match only records with isAvailable=true
}
```

... so basically I wanna match

```sql
records WHERE isAvailable IS TRUE AND (name MATCH searchCondition OR description MATCH searchCondition)
```

I've tried different combinations of filters using `$search.compound`, like this:

```js
[
  {
    $search: {
      index: "index_name", // Atlas Search Index
      compound: {
        filter: [ 
          {
            equals: {
              path: "isAvailable",
              value: true
            }
          }
        ],
        should: [
          {
            autocomplete: {
              query: "search_query",
              path: "name",
              fuzzy: {
                maxExpansions: 10
              }
            }
          },
          {
            autocomplete: {
              query: "search_query",
              path: "description",
              fuzzy: {
                maxExpansions: 10
              }
            }
          }  
        ]
      }
    }
  }
]
```

but neither `filter`, `must`, `mustNot`, or `should` works properly.
Any of them works fine separately (when I pass **exactly one** filter into `$search.compound`), but don't when I trying to combine them.

Can someone helps me figure out how I can reach that? Or, maybe, should I use something else beside `$search.compound`?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your specific case, but why don't you just use a `find`?
You can easily achieve what you want with this : [Playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z_PYEcHA5jq)

```
db.collection.find({
  "$and": [
    {
      "isAvailable": true
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "name": "searchCondition"
        },
        {
          "description": "searchCondition"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Comment: `find` cannot handle Altas Search indexes, sadly